# Flink, odd behavior when using Hadoop Compatibility

Tags: apache-flink

I've add Flink Hadoop Compatibility to the project which reads sequence file from hdfs path,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's the java code snippet,

```
DataSource<Tuple2<NullWritable, BytesWritable>> input = env.createInput(HadoopInputs.readHadoopFile(
    new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat<NullWritable, BytesWritable>(),
    NullWritable.class, BytesWritable.class, path));
```

This works pretty fine when I run it inside my Eclipse, but when I submit it via command line 'flink run ...', it complains,

```
The type returned by the input format could not be automatically determined. Please specify the TypeInformation of the produced type explicitly by using the 'createInput(InputFormat, TypeInformation)' method instead.
```

OK, so I update my code to add type information,

```
DataSource<Tuple2<NullWritable, BytesWritable>> input = env.createInput(HadoopInputs.readHadoopFile(
    new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat<NullWritable, BytesWritable>(),
    NullWritable.class, BytesWritable.class, path),
    TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Tuple2<NullWritable, BytesWritable>>() {}));
```

Now it complains,

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load the TypeInformation for the class 'org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable'. You may be missing the 'flink-hadoop-compatibility' dependency.
```

Some people suggest to copy flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.11-1.5.6.jar to FLINK_HOME/lib, but it doesn't help, still same error.

Does anyone have any clue?

My Flink is a standalone installation, version 1.5.6.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, I copied flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.11-1.5.6.jar to the wrong place, after fixing that, it works.

Now my question is, is there any other way to go? Because copying that jar file to FLINK_HOME/lib is definitely not a good idea to me, especially when talking about a big flink cluster.

Comment: Did you try to create a fat-jar?

Comment: @TobiSH Hi, the jar is created using maven shade plugin, includes everything except flink-java and flink-client (these two uses provided scope), I do look inot the jar file, and I can see class org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable

Comment: @TobiSH, I've updated my post.

Comment: Did I got you right? You fixed the problem by copying `flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.11-1.5.6.jar` to the lib folder of your cluster? Having the right version at the fat-jar doesn't work?

Comment: Yep, packaging flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.11-1.5.6.jar into my fat-jar doesn't help. The only way I've found so far is to copy that jar into FLINK_HOME/lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in version 1.9.0, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12163 for details